# array named for no reason

Tags: arrays, symfony, doctrine

I calling a repository method and passing an array in it for the parameters. But the array is named after the first parameter and I don't understand why.

Here's the call :

```
/**
 * @param $month
 * @param $year
 * @return Conges[]
 */
public function getAllCongesPayes($year, $month)
{
    return $this->congesRepository->getNbCongesByMonth(array('year' => $year, 'month' => $month, 'cngPaye' => true));
}
```

And in the error I can see that :

```
array('year' => array('year' => '2016', 'month' => '05', 'cngPaye' => true)))
```

And of course it's saying "Missing argument 2" because only one array is in it.

Here is the repository method:

```
public function getNbCongesByMonth($year, $month, $conge){
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');

$listOfEntities = $qb
    ->select('count(e) as nb')
    // ->leftjoin('e.cngUsrLogin', 'u')
    ->where(
        $qb->expr()->like('e.cngDateDebut',
            $qb->expr()->literal($year.'-'.$month.'-%')
        )
    )
    ->andWhere('e.congesPayes = :conge')
    // ->andWhere('u.usrGestionCra = 1')
    // ->groupBy('e')
    ->setParameter('conge', $conge)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
return $listOfEntities;
}
```

and the call in the controller :

```
$this->congesService = $this->get("intranet.conges_service");
    $nbCongesPayes = $this->congesService->getAllCongesPayes('2016', '05');
```

If someone could explain why this happens that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'm really dumb and figured it 2 minutes after... Sorry for the post...

Here is the answer :

```
public function getNbCongesByMonth($array){
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');

$listOfEntities = $qb
    ->select('count(e) as nb')
    // ->leftjoin('e.cngUsrLogin', 'u')
    ->where(
        $qb->expr()->like('e.cngDateDebut',
            $qb->expr()->literal($array['year'].'-'.$array['month'].'-%')
        )
    )
    ->andWhere('e.cngPaye = :conge')
    // ->andWhere('u.usrGestionCra = 1')
    // ->groupBy('e')
    ->setParameter('conge', $array['cngPaye'])
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
return $listOfEntities;
}
```

Needed to pass an array in the parameters. I don't know why I did that.
Anyway it's solved

Comment: I was about to answer before I saw this. Actually, I think instead of changing `getNbCongesByMonth($year, $month, $conge)` to `getNbCongesByMonth($array)`, it would have been better to change `return $this->congesRepository->getNbCongesByMonth(array('year' => $year, 'month' => $month, 'cngPaye' => true));` to `return $this->congesRepository->getNbCongesByMonth($year, $month, true);`, since this exposes the parameters of the array better.

Comment: Oh yeah, nice :) Actually it was worth asking ^^ Thanks !